# BlendImage Filter not available When i download from FabricJS builder

Tags: fabricjs, fabricjs2

BlendImage Filter not available When i download from FabricJS builder

I have selected all option from below link

http://fabricjs.com/build/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! It's Fixed. Now you can take [build](http://fabricjs.com/build/).

Comment: fabric.Image.filters.BlendImage not working with cropped image.

Comment: @ShaktiPatel can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @ShaktiPatel update the link in github [issue](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/5005) page as well